# Classic ASP variable scope - I think I have lost my mind

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, scope

It has been a while since I worked with classic asp, I am having complete brain fade regarding variable scope.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=vbscript RUNAT=Server>
dim test
test = "Test it"

function testAsp()
   testasp = "Should be a result here " & test
end function
</SCRIPT>

<html>
<body>
<%
   response.write(testAsp())
%>
</body>
</html>
```

If I move the declaration inside the block all is good. Running server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5. Did something change? Or is it me?

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your case by ticking the empty V icon below its score and arrows. Also, generally speaking always use only `<%` and `%>` unless you explicitly need something different - which I doubt you'll ever really need.

Answer (score 5):

Change your `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=vbscript RUNAT=Server>` to a `<%` and your `</SCRIPT>` to a `%>` and you should be good.

You are getting caught by the order in which script engines execute during the classic ASP life cycle.  It's confusing, but the `<SCRIPT />` block will execute AFTER the `<% %>` block, even though it comes first in the order of the source.  I cannot readily explain why the function is defined in the `<% %>` block, but I expect it has to do with function hoisting.

To further clarify, this is the order you get out of the box (assuming VBScript is configured as your default language):

1. JScript contained in `<script runat="server" language="jscript" />`
2. Inline VBscript, contained in `<% %>` blocks
3. VBScript contained in `<script runat="server" language="vbscript" />`

Comment: Wow - that was simple - for you :) I spent all morning on this! My site was done using V Interdev. And this same type of code seems to be working in the rest of my pages. I really have to take a look at the distinctions. And try and figure out the order they are executed in. Vinterdev puts script blocks all over! Thanks, now I have a place to start.